# Rest service that returns clipboard contents in Java

Tags: java, rest, clipboard

I need to get the clipboard content of the remote computer. I wrote a REST service with following code:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
//clipboard.setContents(new StringSelection("test"), this);
String result = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);`
```

But this service throws an Exception:

```
java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException: Unicode String
```

That means that `clipboard.getData` returns null.

Wenn I start this code in java without rest service then clipboard content is returned. Is it possible that tomcat has no rights to work with system clipboard or an incorrect clipboard is selected?

Has anybody worked with clipboard per REST service? What I am doing wrong? Are there other possibilities to get the clipboard of a remote computer?

Comment: What do you expect? That your REST service reads the clippboard of the client machine?

Comment: Are you trying to read the content from the **server's** clipboard?

Comment: @BetaRide, he wants the clipboard from the server, obviously.

Comment: OP writes "I need to get the clipboard content of the remote computer."

Comment: Did you make sure, that your clipboard contains *plain text* when trying to access it?

Comment: @BetaRide actually that was my edit :) OP wrote "I need to get a clipboard content on the remote computer." in the original text. The "of" was my interpretation :D

Comment: My task is to read a clipboard on remote comuter. I had an idea to implement a small service on remote computer that returns me a clipboard content. But this doesn't work as expected. :( Clipboard contains plain text and I can get it with java code execution in IDE, but same code doesn't work as service.